# Cannot clear cookies in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I want to clear cookies when I logout of WordPress. I have seen many posts with the same problem. The suggested answers do not work for me.
My code...

```
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user( 0 );
    unset($_COOKIE['sso']);
    setcookie('sso', '', time()-38000, '/');
    do_action( 'wp_logout', $user_id );
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['sso'])) {
      do_action( 'wp_logout', $user_id );
```

What is weird, is that I do get logged out based on the fact that PHP says the cookie is empty "if(!isset($_COOKIE['sso']))". So PHP says the cookie is empty but the browser still has the cookie. It seems that PHP is not setting browser cookie and doing it's own cookie thing!

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check Local Storage vs cookies. Without knowing more about what you are specifically using its hard to replicate. However, local storage is limited to the domain for access and is a lot safer and persists till actually cleared.

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: thanks for your response. I suppose, I can use LSV for my purpose with with a TTL, however the change would be slightly inconvenient but mainly it is bugging me because I need to know how or why the cookie is "re-inventing" itself after a forced expiry? :)

Comment: Are you able to share what you are using for SSO? I'm assuming it is a plugin.

Comment: I have written a plugin and the code I shared above is the logout function in the plugin. The logout portion works and the user is logged out but cookies does not clear. This is so frustrating. I am sure this is a bug in PHP.